# How to reduce the response time of request where response is JSON?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, json, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a index.html page where I make an ajax call and I get the JSON data on success of ajax and send the JSON to other functions.

```
$.ajax({
    type : "GET",
    url : 'get_data',
    dataType : 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        update_page(data.info);
    }
})
```

In the controller I have

```
  def get_data
    parents = Parent.all
    students = Student.all
    teachers = Teacher.all
    schools = School.all

    @collection = {"parents" => parents, "students" => students, "teachers" => teachers, "schools" => schools}

    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render json: Oj.dump({"info" => @collection.to_json(:except=>  [:created_at, :updated_at] ) }) }
    end
  end
```

There are around `1500` records in each Model. It takes lot of time to respond and also memory consumption is also high. I have used `new relic` to trace the response time and it took around `12000ms` and I have used `oink` and other tools like `rack mini profiler` and it shows the memory consumption and response time higher but I am not sure on how to fix this issue.

Please help me solve this. I have been trying for the past two days and I could not find a solution.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The basic idea is to only query the amount of data that you need. Do you really need all the records (1500 records * 4 models = 6000 records) all the time? Just look at StackOverflow, there are thousands of questions but on one page a user only need to see around 50 questions. Maybe you want to implement pagination for your page.

**UPDATE**

If loading all the records at start up is a must. You might want to look at browser offline storage. You will load all your data once, store it in browsers and use the offline data instead of querying all the data per request. This is for Firefox. You can easily find something similar for other browsers.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Apps/Build/Offline

Comment: Sorry, I actually use these data to show up on the Google maps and hence I need all those data in the same page

Comment: @Logesh Are you sure that at any points in time, your users need to see all the schools/teachers/parents/students? I imagine your map will start at a location where there are only about tens of schools and that's the amount of data you need to query. When your user browses to a new location on your map, more data will be loaded. How about that?

Comment: That's a good idea but it doesn't fit for me as initially I would zoom such that all markers in the map are shown and they may be clustered. Tapping on the cluster I would break up to show.

Comment: If each marker represents a school, you just need to query all schools at startup. Teachers/parents/students will only be queries when needed.

Comment: But I have got to show the location of all of them in the map. Basically I cannot reduce the data that I get but I want to reduce the response duration by any other means.

Comment: You might want to look at my update on browser-based offline storage. Rails has its own SQL caching mechanism but that wouldn't help much due to the number of records (6000 records) you want to query at one time.

Answer (score 0):

Consider disk or memory [caching](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html). Whatever is bottle neck, SQL query or JSON serialization, it will be blaze fast while serving from disk. First request will be cached, obviously it will take long time, but only once. However you must take care about cache invalidation by your self. I'm pretty sure it will worth it.